# SQL Server : Combining Rows

Tags: sql, sql-server

I've been trying to slim this query down so that I get one row per vendor id and remit I

```
-- Insert statements for procedure here
SELECT DISTINCT
mast.VENDOR AS VendorID,
mast.VENDOR_VNAME AS VendorName, 
addr.LOCATION_CODE AS 'Remit ID',   
mast.TAX_ID AS TIN, 
addr.ADDR1 AS Address1, 
addr.ADDR2 AS Address2, 
addr.CITY_ADDR5 AS City, 
addr.STATE_PROV AS St, 
addr.COUNTRY AS Country, 
addr.POSTAL_CODE AS Zip, 
count(inv.TRAN_TOT_TXBL) AS InvoiceCT,
SUM(inv.TRAN_TOT_TXBL) AS InvoiceAMT,
COUNT(inv.TRAN_PAID_AMT) AS PaymentCT,
SUM(inv.TRAN_PAID_AMT) AS PaymentAmt,
inv.CASH_CODE AS PaymentMethod,
inv.TERMS_CD AS PayTerm,    
'' AS POCt, 
'' AS DPO,
'' AS SourceSystem, 
contact.PHONE_NMBR AS 'Phone Number', 
contact.E_MAIL_ADDRESS AS 'E-mail', 
contact.FAX_NMBR AS 'Fax Number'

FROM APINVOICE inv
INNER JOIN APVENMAST mast ON mast.VENDOR = inv.VENDOR AND mast.VENDOR_GROUP =     inv.VENDOR_GROUP AND mast.VENDOR_STATUS ='A'
INNER JOIN APVENADDR addr ON addr.VENDOR = mast.VENDOR AND (addr.CUR_ADDR='Y' AND addr.VENDOR_GROUP = mast.VENDOR_GROUP)
INNER JOIN APCONTACT contact ON contact.VENDOR = mast.VENDOR AND contact.VENDOR_GROUP = mast.VENDOR_GROUP
WHERE inv.INVOICE_DTE BETWEEN '1/1/2012' AND '12/31/2013' AND (inv.VENDOR_GROUP = '2' OR inv.VENDOR_GROUP = '35')
GROUP BY mast.VENDOR,mast.VENDOR_VNAME,mast.TAX_ID,addr.ADDR1,addr.CITY_ADDR5,addr.STATE_PROV,addr.C  OUNTRY,addr.POSTAL_CODE,addr.ADDR2,contact.PHONE_NMBR,contact.E_MAIL_ADDRESS,contact.FAX_NMBR,addr.LOCATION_CODE,inv.TERMS_CD,inv.CASH_CODE
ORDER BY mast.VENDOR,mast.VENDOR_VNAME,mast.TAX_ID,addr.ADDR1,addr.CITY_ADDR5,addr.STATE_PROV,addr.COUNTRY,addr.POSTAL_CODE,addr.ADDR2,contact.PHONE_NMBR,contact.E_MAIL_ADDRESS,contact.FAX_NMBR,addr.LOCATION_CODE,inv.TERMS_CD,inv.CASH_CODE
```

I'm getting results like

```
   VendorID VendorName  RemitID TIN Address1    Address2    City    St  Country Zip InvoiceCT   InvoiceAMT  PaymentCT   PaymentAmt  PaymentMethod   PayTerm POCt    DPO SourceSystem    PhoneNumber E-mail  FaxNumber
    3   20 Company 1 INC                    123456789            EAST STREET                                            WEST SIDE           NY                                  14787       9   0.00    9   30409.39    371                                                                                                                        
    3   20 Company 1 INC                    123456789            EAST STREET                                            WEST SIDE           NY                                  14787       7   0.00    7   10128.22    371     PNOW
```

The columns populated are `VendorID`, `VendorName`, `Tin`, `Address1`, `City`, `St`, `Zip InvoiceCT`, `InvoiceAmt`, `PaymentCT`, `PaymentAmt` and `Pay Term`.

Everything else from this example is blank

The result is giving the numbers and everything that I need but I need both lines to be combined into 1 line and the numbers of each should be added into one another to give me a bigger sum.

I'm lost!

Comment: I can't tell which columns they are, and I haven't read that query yet, but just skimming, you have 7's on the bottom row where you have 9's on the top. That is why DISTINCT isn't combining them. They are different rows.

Comment: Those are aggregate fields, actually, the only problem is the PNOW at the far right of the 2nd line.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The two lines differ by TERMS_CD, one is PNOW and the other is blank, since you're grouping on that field, the two lines are returned.  If you take the MIN/MAX of that field, you will get the one line you desire.

You have to decide which fields contribute to a distinct value in your situation.

Comment: This helps answer the bigger question.  There is a lot more data involved than the one I presented. Thank you

Answer (score 1):

You have the two rows because they have different values in the PayTerm column

```
PayTerm   blank / PNOW
```

include this column as some sort of aggregate rather than the raw column e.g. max(PayTerm) or 
exclude it from the query altogether.